# django rest_frameworks not getting data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get dates from my model database. When I request for getting all objects, it only shows `{}`.

I want to get and post a date using django-restapi

Here is my code:

My serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import prediction_model


class predserializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = prediction_model
        field = '__all__'
```

my model:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class prediction_model(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

    def meta(self):
        return self.date
```

my views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import prediction_model
from .serializers import predserializer

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'homesite/index.html')


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_date(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prediction = prediction_model.objects.all()
        serializer = predserializer(prediction)
        return Response(serializer.data)


def post_date(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = predserializer(data=request.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: You need to add **`many=True`** as **`serializer = predserializer(prediction, many=True)`**

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit from [serializers.ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

```
class predserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

And you need to pass [`many=True`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects) when passing your queryset to the serializer

```
serializer = predserializer(prediction, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**serializers.py** file should be:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import prediction_model


class predserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = prediction_model
        field = '__all__'
```

And in **views.py** should be:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import prediction_model
from .serializers import predserializer

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'homesite/index.html')


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_date(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        prediction = prediction_model.objects.all()
        serializer = predserializer(prediction, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


def post_date(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = predserializer(data=request.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```